# Is it possible to make camera tracking without moving the whole world?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I don't really want to move the whole world in my game but I do want the screen to follow my character.

So for example, normally pygame would render at the position of 0,0 and the window height width would allow you to expand that viewing area. But I want to move the starting position so that I can view something at coordinates 1000x1000 even if my screen is only 500x500 big.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to make camera tracking without moving the whole world?

No.

By relativity, moving the player within the world is the same as moving the world around the player.  Since your camera is fixed on the player, by definition you will see the world moving when the player moves within it.  Therefore, you must draw your world in a different place.

It is more explicit in 3D graphics; we represent the scene's motion as one matrix, and the camera's as another.  The renderer uses their product.  It doesn't care which contributed to the motion.